# Sort image by date upload in opencart 3.0.2.0 Image Manager

Tags: php, sorting, opencart, opencart-3

I want to sort image by date upload in Imange Manager Opencart 3.0.2.0 by fix in PHP code or ocmod?
Anyone know the way to do this.

Thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this file:

```
admin\controller\common\filemanager.php
```

Find:

```
$files = glob($directory . '/' . $filter_name . '*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif,JPG,JPEG,PNG,GIF}', GLOB_BRACE);
```

Add after:

```
array_multisort(array_map('filemtime', $files), SORT_NUMERIC, SORT_DESC, $files);
```